# Как сделать в VS 2015 аналог ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать в *VS 2015* аналог `ListBox`, но с возможностью пользовательского редактирования данных, то есть по сути таблицу состоящую из `textbox`?

Использовать сами `textbox` не могу, т.к. постоянно может требовать их разное количество, а `listbox` не подходит, т.к. требуется авто-выведение списка цен и иногда их редактирование уже в процессе пользования.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Здравствуйте. WinForms.

Comment: в таблице должно быть несколько столбцов? в ячейках могут быть текстовые поля / выпадающие списки / контролы? если да и да, то посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> таблицу состоящую из textbox

Если в таблице должно быть несколько столбцов, то в WinForms можно использовать DataGridView, у которого можно определить тип выводимых ячеек.

Например, чтобы в ячейках выводились TextBox надо использовать DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.

```
class Data {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var f = new Form();
var g = new DataGridView() {
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    AutoGenerateColumns = false,
    AllowUserToAddRows = false,
    AllowUserToDeleteRows = false
};
g.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { 
               HeaderText = "value", 
               DataPropertyName="Value" 
              });
var l = new BindingList<Data>();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    l.Add(new Data() { Value = "v"+i });
g.DataSource = l;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Значение свойств Data.Value выводятся в DataGridView и их можно редактировать, а изменения передаются обратно в Data.Value.

Если надо добавить столбец, то в Data надо добавить свойство и добавить еще один столбец в DataGridView.Columns.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую помудрить с этим делом.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться контролом [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx): если поставить свойство [`LabelEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.labeledit.aspx) в true, то текст можно редактировать. При этом свойство [`Activation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.activation.aspx) отвечает за переход в режим редактирования: по одинарному клику (`ItemActivation.OneClick`) или по двойному клику (`ItemActivation.TwoClick`). Добавление новой записи программно может выглядеть так:

```
ListViewItem item = listView.Items.Add(String.Empty);
item.BeginEdit(); // переходим врежим редактирования текущей записи
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться контролом [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) и задать ему одну колонку. Хотя этот вариант будет выглядеть менее красиво.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, огромное. Буду пробовать.

Comment: К сожалению, строки в ListView добавляются как объекты и их нельзя редактировать,(( LabelEdit, видать, отвечает за как таковое имя объекта в ListView