# BindingList и привязка данных

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list

У меня есть лист в который я могу добавить\удалить какой-то объект , как сделать чтобы на это событие сразу отреагировал ListBox?

Comment: лучше использовать DataGridView, т.к. у него больше разных настроек. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477612/), но если нужен ListBox, то см. мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо привязать ListBox к коллекции

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

var bl = new BindingList<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
new Timer { Enabled=true, Interval=1000 } // для примера каждую секунду 
    .Tick += (s, e) => bl.AddNew();       // добавляем новые элементы в bl
var f = new Form();
var lb = new ListBox() { 
           Parent = f, 
           Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
           DataSource = bl         // привязка ListBox к BindingList 
           };
f.ShowDialog();
```

---

Если надо в ListBox выводить значение свойства, то в lb надо добавить ValueMember

```
var lb = new ListBox() {     
           DataSource = bl,
           ValueMember = "тут имя свойства";
           };
```

---

Если в ListBox надо выводить изменения свойств объектов, то в объектах надо реализовать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    // требуется для уведомления о изменении значения свойств.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public long Value {
        get { return _Value; }
        internal set {
            if (_Value != value) {
                _Value = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }}}
    long _Value = 0;
}
```

Работающий пример на c# [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477539/196972).

---

**UPDATE**

> в лист добавляю число 1, а в лист бокс должна вывестись не единица, а "Число 1"

Проще всего сделать так

```
class Data {   
   public int Value { get; set; } 
   public string Text { get { return "Число " + this.Value; } } 
}
var bl = new BindingList<Data>() { 
           new Data { Value = 1 } 
           };
var lb = new ListBox() { 
           Parent = f, 
           DataSource = bl, 
           ValueMember="Value", 
           DisplayMember="Text" 
           };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда происходит добавление в лист, какое событие приходит листбоксу? Мне нужно чтобы лист бокс реагировал на добавление в биндинг лист, но выполнял то что я пропишу.

Comment: @Lightness т.к. тут привязка данных, то событие добавления лучше перехватывать в BindingList.ListChanged

Comment: допустим я в лист добавляю число 1, а в лист бокс должна вывестись не единица, а "Число 1". Как обработать BindingList.ListChanged ?

Comment: @Lightness _"допустим я в лист добавляю число 1, а в лист бокс должна вывестись не единица, а "Число 1"_ -- сейчас напишу и добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @Lightness _"допустим я в лист добавляю число 1, а в лист бокс должна вывестись не единица, а "Число 1"_ -- добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно воспользоваться [ListControl.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx)

```
List<SomeType> someList = ...;
listBox.DataSource = someList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявляем класс с данными:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Создаем коллекцию объектов:

```
var source = new BindingList<Person>()
{
    new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan" }
};
```

Настраиваем контрол и передаем ему данные:

```
// свойство, которое будет отображаться
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
// свойство, которое будет возвращаться в качестве значения выбранного айтема
listBox.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox = source;
```

После этого все изменения в `source` будут отображаться в контроле.